# AQL query with updatingdocuments from two collections runs as transaction or not?

Tags: transactions, arangodb, aql, arangodb-php

I have a question about transactions in arangodb, if I run below AQL query, will it be executed as one transaction or will it be separated into two transaction? My backend is php:

```
LET r1 = (FOR u IN Users UPDATE u WITH { status: "inactive" } IN Users)
LET r2 = (FOR b IN Blogs UPDATE b WITH { status: "inactive" } IN Blogs)
RETURN true
```

For now I am using transaction as arangodb documentation suggests (using javascript code), but if using AQL query is possible, I'd prefer to remove js code from my php code!

If it's possible, do you suggest this solution for commiting transactions or using js way is preferred?

Answer (score 3):

AQL in a single server environment is executed in an ACID fashion. This is automatically within a single transaction without any further need of a separate `_executeTransaction`. Therefore you can use the above AQL statement to update the two collections within a single AQL statement.

There are some caveat to keep in mind:

- after the update statement for a collection you cannot use this particular collection in any further update or read statement
- if you enable intermediate commits then the update will no longer be atomic

Comment: thanks for answer, it was very helpful.
i'm using RocksDB but i dont know that intermediate commit is enable or not. how can i check it?

Comment: Frank, could you point me at the docs/reference for that? Wan'st aware a single server environment acted differently. Good to know.

Comment: The documentation https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Operations/Insert.html and the option is described https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Programs/Arangod/Options.html#rocksdb-options

Answer (score 2):

(edited from original)

According to the docs:

> Each UPDATE operation is restricted to a single collection, and the
>   collection name must not be dynamic. Only a single UPDATE statement
>   per collection is allowed per AQL query, and it cannot be followed by
>   read or write operations that access the same collection, by traversal
>   operations, or AQL functions that can read documents.

In order to [trigger a transaction you need to do so explicitly](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Transactions/TransactionInvocation.html).

> There are no individual BEGIN, COMMIT or ROLLBACK transaction commands
>   in ArangoDB. Instead, a transaction in ArangoDB is started by
>   providing a description of the transaction to the
>   db._executeTransaction JavaScript function:

```
db._executeTransaction(description);
```

For example:

```
db._executeTransaction({
  collections: {
    write: [ "users", "logins" ],
    read: [ "recommendations" ]
  }
});
```

So, to answer the question, you need to use a client library to trigger a transaction as it will not happen automatically.

That being said, the main benefit of document/graph databases is the horizontal scaling, sharding, and cluster abilities. If you absolutely need to rely on transactions you might want to rethink why you are using a document based database. [Eventual Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) is typically good enough for a lot of use cases but in other cases you absolutely need [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)). A blog *probably* doesn't need ACID.

Comment: i want to point to important word on line 2 of what you mentioned:
... single UPDATE statement **per collection** is allowed per AQL query ...
so in my case because updates affect two different collections , i see no problem but i can not be sure about it!

Comment: @AmirrezaShafaat I see your point, I interpreted it differently.

Comment: @AmirrezaShafaat found more information regarding transactions and updated the answer.

Comment: I wanted to point out and emphasize what @AndrewGrothe has said about Eventual Consistency. ACID is expensive, very expensive, and if you need a lot of simultaneous transactions, you will get a lot of write-write conflicts with ArangoDB and performance will deep-dive. Do yourself a favor and use a DB with eventual consistency if you can live with it.